# Install all JSPM dependencies in gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp, jspm

I want to have one command to download all dependencies the project need. This should be a `gulp dependencies`. I have a JSPM dependencies in the fronted and I can install them by typing `jspm install` in the command line. I want to automate it with gulp (it would take care about other dependencies, too, like pip, composer etc).

Here is what I have tried:

```
gulp.task('dependencies', ['deps-composer', 'deps-jspm', 'deps-pip']);

// others

gulp.task('deps-jspm', function (done) {
  require('jspm').install().then(done);
});
```

However, it only creates an empty `jspm_packages` directory and does not download anything.

I have succeeded with the following

```
gulp.task('deps-jspm', function (done) {
  require('child_process').execSync('jspm install');
});
```

but it looks like an overkill and it requires the jspm to be installed globally.

The directory structure is *normal*, i.e. there is a `package.json`, `config.js` and `gulpfile.js` in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jspm.install()` expects a package name as its first argument in order to install a specific package. If you want to install **all** packages you have to pass `true` (see [the docs](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/api.md#package-manager-api)):

```
gulp.task('deps-jspm', function (done) {
  require('jspm').install(true).then(done);
});
```